# How does asynchrony deal with variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Suppose I have the following code

```
var x = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     x = x + i;
}

launch(x);


function launch(x) {
     console.log(x);
}
```

Does the async nature of javascript mean that the function `launch` may be called before the `for` cycle is over? Or is it called only after the operations on `x` are over? How to ensure the latter?

**UPDATE: I use it in a Node.Js app**

Comment: Your code runs synchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. This would only be true if the `for` cycle would run asynchronously.

The function `launch` will be always caused after the loop exits. The difference could be if you had something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     somethingAsync(i);
}

launch(x);
```

The loop would still finish first, but the `somethingAsync(i)` might not, since it is running asynchronously. The loop always runs synchronously, only the contents of the loop might run asynchronously. You have to know if the function you're calling is synchronous/asynchronous.

If the loop body was asynchronous, you'd have to do a lot more work to run the function `launch(x)` after everything in the loop returns. The concept for this is called *promises*, which basically allow you to say things like *here's a list of asynchronous operations, run this other thing after all those operations finish*.

Here are a few references on promises

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://www.promisejs.org/

**Update:** The above mentioned is true for both Node.js and the browser. The semantics of JavaScript as the language are the same in both cases.

Comment: Ok, and For cycle actually runs synchronously? Thanks!

Comment: @deemeetree yes exactly, the loop itself runs synchronously.

Comment: thank you so much! And how do I know if something runs asynchronously? Is it just that the functions are always called in an async manner?

Comment: @deemeetree Yes only functions can run asynchronously. The only way to know is to look at the documentation or the source code for each function. Most of the time you can tell this by what the function is doing. All I/O in Node.js is by default asynchronus, so if you're reading from a file, etc., it will be asynchronous. You can also tell an async function by the fact that it accepts a callback as one of its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is completely synchronous and deterministic until you actually invoke an asynchronous construct like `setTimeout` or an asynchronous HTTP request. That code will execute in order.

Comment: What if the for cycle was hidden inside a function, so I invoke one function and then – another one. Then I might lose the results of the first function, right?

Answer (score 0):

This code will run synchronously because there's no asynch call (like $.get, $.ajax, and some stuff from jquery)